# when Swapshop came along

Tags: phrase-meaning

I guess "when Swapshop came along" mean "when Swapshop (a shop when second-hand goods are swapped) became fashionable." Am I on the right track?

> (A Brit posted the following on an American website):
> We never had Saturday Morning telly for children when I was a kid, not until my teens **when Swapshop came along**. I imagine Australia wasn’t much different.

> You always assume that other countries do the same thing as Americans, they don't.

Comment: Nah. [Multi-Coloured Swap Shop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-Coloured_Swap_Shop) was a British children's television series that aired on BBC1 from 2 October 1976 to 27 March 1982. But that should be obvious from the context, since it comes right after *We never had **Saturday Morning telly for children** when I was a kid* (which I *seriously* doubt would be true; Saturday morning kids TV probably started in the UK in the 50s).

Comment: Did you look up the [meaning of **come along**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/come-along)?  Also, "Swapshop" was the name of a TV show.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - kid's TV in the UK was pretty heavily rationed in the 1950s and 60s, and the type of programming that ' Multi-Coloured Swap Shop' is an example of was a product of the 1970s. The pioneer was ATV's 'Today Is Saturday' in 1974 and Swap Shop came along two years later. Before that it was just educational programmes and the odd cartoon if you were lucky.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: [Blue Peter is a British children's television programme that was first broadcast in **1958**.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Peter) Probably not on Saturday morning though, I grant you! :) In the early 60s I was packed off with my older sibling to cheap "Saturday morning matinee" sessions at the local cinema. Before that, it was *Watch with Mother* in the ***afternoons*** in the 50s.

Comment: Blue Peter was 5 PM on Thursdays for 15 minutes and extended to 20 minutes in 1960 and moved to Mondays. My first crush was Valerie Singleton, although my dad preferred [Leila Williams](https://www.famousfix.com/topic/leila-williams), Miss Great Britain 1957, (born 1937) who was the first female co-presenter in 1958

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the 1960s there were some programmes on Saturday morning TV in the UK that kids would enjoy, old re-runs of Roy Rogers, Popeye, etc, but the continuous all-morning live format of Swap Shop etc came very much later. On Saturday 17 January 1959 the first programme on BBC TV was 'Grandstand', a sports show, at 1.30 PM.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasal verb *come along* means arrive or appear, as shown below.  This dictionary does not specifically mention *fashionable* in its definition, but in this context I  think it is not wrong to interpret the way you have done.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-along

> come along
> — phrasal verb with come verb

> to arrive or appear at a place:

> Go now and I'll come along later.

> You wait half an hour for a bus, then three come along at once!